# Equivalent expression to "cast pearls before swine"

Tags: word-choice

I'm translating a novel that has an expression that means "cast pearls before swine." i.e., it would be wasted on them.

She caresses the top of his head as she protests that a roast pig would **be wasted on these people**.

Does anyone know an equivalent expression that is a little more colorful? Doesn't have to be in wide use. The biblical expression seems out of place in this character's mouth, but my current solution seems a little bland. (Also they are literally discussing eating a pig.)   THANKS!

Comment: Hard to be specific without knowing more about your story and style, but you could certainly make up your own phrase along the same lines (giving an iPhone 14 to a caveman?)

Comment: Even though the phrase has its origin in the religion, it doesn't seem like a biblical expression to me. Its been used enough outside of religion to have a cultural feel to it.

Comment: There is a comic strip by stephen Pastis about anthromorphic animals called Pearls Before Swine.  That seems like  a relativly secular use of the phrase.  
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearls_Before_Swine_(comics)    - see also   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearls_Before_Swine

Comment: Why is a roast pig a waste on these people?

Answer (score 1):

## One of *those* people:

Such condescending expressions have gone out of favor in more recent history, so finding anything modern will be difficult. A lot depends on who is saying it, and to whom. It could be racist, political, or class-conscious, all of which would require different answers.

I also don't know what limits you might have trying to provide a translation, so I can't really address that part. A different expression will not match the original.

If I was making up an expression on my own, I'd say. "**It's cannibalism to feed roasted pork to uncultured swine**." This is elitist. To subtly flip the tone, you could go "**It's cannibalism to feed roasted pork to these arrogant pigs.**" and you have the same sentiment but from the opposite viewpoint (used perhaps more ironically). If you simply want to make a racist insult, then say "**Roast pork? For them? Isn't that cannibalism?**" or simply "**Isn't that feeding swine to swine?**" A dismissive statement like "**Wouldn't spam be more appropriate for *their* kind?**" would also make the point, with a less indignant tone, and could be either elitist or racist. [Spam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spam_(food)) was invented in 1937, so older historical periods wouldn't fit this usage.

You could also extend the analogy, so you might say, "**That's like feeding caviar to pigs.**"

A more generic expression I've heard is "You can't clean dirt."  It implies unworthiness that can't be fixed by efforts to add culture. So, added to secondary sentences to clarify meaning,"**Roast pork? For *them*? What a waste. You can't clean dirt.**"

If you're trying to keep with a pig theme, "You can't make a silk purse from a sow's ear" is saying that you can't make something fine from a base starting point (a very un-PC expression nowadays). This *might* be an inversion of your needs.

Not sure if this helps. "Living high off the hog" is a reference to eating the best (high) parts of the pig, and the wealthy ate "high off the hog" while common people had to eat the lesser parts. Today, the lowest parts (the pork ribs) have been transformed by great African-American cooks to the most coveted parts (great irony).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the phrase *casting swine before pearls* where the word *pearls* is used ironically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this fits the tone of your writing, or your characters. It's more P.G. Wodehouse, and it does happen to fit my style.

I love inverting cliches, e.g. Churchill referring to a Parliamentary opponent as a "sheep in sheep's clothing."

So: "casting swine before Pearl" (in fact, I would name a minor character "Pearl" just so I can use that!)